# Error en data de metas

Tags: powerbi, dax

Buenas noches colegas,

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo un objeto visual (Matriz) donde tengo información de ventas, cantidad de pacientes atendidos por especialidad y sus respectivas metas tanto de pacientes como montos facturados.

Resulta que la data de las metas se tuvo que construir por aparte a la información de ventas y pacientes se hizo en un excel con los siguientes campos: compañía, centrod, cod_clasif (especialidad), monto_meta (meta facturación) , meta_PX (meta pacientes) y fecha.

Resulta que mi problema deriva en que la data de las metas tanto de montos como de cantidad de pacientes no me esta mostrando la data correcta.

Mi relación esta así, tabla IVD (facturación) tabla Metas, ambas las relaciono por el código de clasificación y tengo otra tabla de centros (sucursales) que la ligo a la tabla IVD por el centro.

Tengo filtros de fecha (tabla IVD) y sucursales (tabla centros).

¿Tienen alguna sugerencia o idea del por que me estará dando error la data de las metas #powerbi #DAX?

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede resolver de diferentes formas. La manera más académica es tener solo una tabla de hechos, por lo que en Power BI solo deberías tener la tabla *IVD* con los datos provenientes de las dos tablas.

Para ello, debes fusionar la tabla *IVD* con la tabla *Metas* en Power Query para intentar tener de un conjunto de datos coherente y lo más eficiente posible con [esquema de estrella](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/guidance/star-schema).

Esto lo puedes hacer mediante la opción "Combinar consultas", indicando la relación que tienen las dos tablas